# How to parse xml with &lt; using XmlStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, xmlstreamreader

I am trying to parse xml files. But there is an issue with < .

My XML file example:

```
<title>
<subtitle> The conclusion is p &lt; 0.1 </subtitle>
</title>
```

My code is:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(StringSource);
while (reader.hasNext()) {
switch (reader.next()) {
 case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT: {
  String tagName = reader.getLocalName();
  String path = parent.getPath() + "/" + tagName;
  
   parent.addChild(child);
  }
case XMLStreamReader.CHARACTERS: {
String text = reader.getText();
```

After parsing it, the text I got is: "0.1".

The output I expected is "The conclusion is p < 0.1"

I think the problem is at getText(), how can I fix that?

Comment: An XML parser can split text and supply it to the application in multiple chunks. It can split it anywhere it fancies, but splitting at entity boundaries is often convenient because that avoids shuffling characters within a text buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you think the problem is getText(), Then rewrite as reader.toString() instead of getText();

Here you can see a parse code.

```
tring resumen = "";
XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new FileInputStream(fileName));
xmlEventReader.nextEvent();

while (xmlEventReader.hasNext()) {
     XMLEvent xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();

     if (xmlEvent.isStartElement()) {
         StartElement startElement = xmlEvent.asStartElement();

        if (startElement.getName().getLocalPart().equals("subtitle")) {
           xmlEvent = xmlEventReader.nextEvent();
           resumen = xmlEvent.toString();                            
        }
     }
```

}